# Estilo não propagar para os parents

Tags: html, css

Tenho vários elementos um dentro do outro e quando passo o mouse com o hover ele adiciona uma borda para identificação do elemento, porém, como todos tem a mesma classe, todos os items pegam a borda.

Eu quero que apenas o elemento posicionado com o mouse conseguisse a borda, isso é possível?

Segue exemplo do problema:

```css
.test
{
    width: 100%;
    float:left;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.test:hover
{
    outline: #000 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
    teste
    <br>
    <div class="test">
        teste2
        <br>
        <div class="test">
            teste3
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

O que você pretende não é possível dessa maneira.

Em parte por que o CSS funciona assim, note que a primeira letra de CSS quer dizer "Cascata", ou seja as regras são aplicadas de parente para descendente; e em parte porque está a fazer de maneira que não ajuda.

Se quiser usar esse HTML vai ter de fazer isso com javascript. O melhor seria usar listas, que são feitas/pensadas para esse tipo de código.

Exemplo utilizando JavaScript:

```js
$(function(){
    var testes = $('.test');
    testes.on('mouseover mouseout', function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        testes.removeClass('ativo');
        $(event.target).addClass('ativo');
    });
});
```

```css
.test {
    width: 100%;
    float:left;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.ativo {
    outline: #000 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">teste
    <br>
    <div class="test">teste2
        <br>
        <div class="test">teste3
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: é, eu sei como funciona e recorri aqui por precisar usar e não conhecer nada parecido, talvez quem sabe, mas, enfim, vou ir pro JavaScript mesmo... Valeu

Comment: @CaioGomes ok. Pois é, enquanto houver parentes/descendentes com a mesma classe esse problema vai surgir. Juntei uma sugestão com JavaScript/jQuery caso lhe seja útil.